Confusion regarding standard generator matrix
I think I have a misconception regarding standard generator matrices. Let $G$ be a generator matrix for a code. Then by performing row operations we can put it in reduced row-echelon form. These matrices generate the same code. We call the matrix in reduced row-echelon form the standard generator matrix.
Now; it is very common in coding theory to work with generator matrices of the form $G=(I_k|A)$. However, if I am not mistaken, not every generator matrix can be put into this form. For instance, I believe the matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$
cannot be put into this form. However, what I do believe is that if we have a code $\mathcal{C}$ then it is equivalent to one having a generator matrix of the form $G=(I_k|A)$. Is this correct?

Correct. All you need to do is to permute the columns of the matrix in a reduced row-echelon form in such a way that the columns with the leading $1$s are on the left (from top to bottom). With your example row-echelon matrix it would suffice to swap the second and the third columns.

Possible duplicate targets 1, 2.

Yes, your reasoning is correct.
Your matrix is in reduced row echelon form. So there is no generator matrix of the form $(I_k | A)$, since those are in reduced row echelon form, too, and the reduced row echelon form is unique.
However, any generator matrix $G$ in reduced row echelon form is equivalent to one of the form $(I_k | A)$, as you can permute the pivot positions $i_1 < i_2 < \ldots < i_k$ to the positions $1,\ldots,k$.

@kubo: Thanks for accepting! If the answer was helpful to you, please don't forget the upvote.
